# BOX authentication error

Tags: ios, objective-c, box-api

After entering login details and by authenticating successfully in web view my simulator displays a white screen.I have used this code for authenticating in my view did load

```
UIViewController *authorizationController = [[BoxAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithAuthorizationURL:[[BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session authorizeURL] redirectURI:nil];
[self presentViewController:authorizationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

How to pass from the white screen ?

Comment: You can see example at: https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-sample-app/tree/master/BoxSDKSampleApp

Comment: You can set delegate when create the BoxAuthorizationViewController and implement its delegate methods like  that example. My notice is: " -(BOOL)authorizationViewController:(BoxAuthorizationViewController *)authorizationViewController shouldLoadReceivedOAuth2RedirectRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request" which is implemented in BoxAuthorizationNavigationController.m